# Chat application Integration in IPhone using Objective C

Tags: ios, iphone, chat, livechat

I created an application where user can chat with Trainer at any time. I need a medium to send and receive messages like instant messenger. I don't want to buy third party SDK's , because I need to store all messages and attachments in my server DB.

> I searched in google, every chat app was integrated through **parse** or **push notification** . Will that give more convenient integration procedure? But from my studies, notification willn't help for chat, because If APN server has multiple messages in queue it'll send only the latest one, Finally I will lack my past messages.

1. I need a class files or anything to communicate between two users.
2. Need notification for new messages.
3. Want to store all chats in my server DB.

Is this requirement sounds good??? If possible can you please help me to find out the way?

Comment: i think multipeer connectivity framework will work.. it works over wifi as well as bluetooth. Its is a new framework released in iOS 7

Comment: you can use XMPP framework for chat application. https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework

Comment: @DHEERAJ thanks..but It'll support for my application..Expert and user will not use the same Wifi and will not stay in range for BLE all the times.

Comment: Why not look at Ray Wenderlich's push notification tutorial? It is written for iOS6 but with small delegate changes, it will work on iOS8. It explains notifications as well creating simple chat app that you can build upon http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: I think you should use http://socket.io/ - http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-on-ios/ .